# VSCode: How to prevent editor expansion while double checking on upper tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using split screen in vscode, double clicking on the superior tab kinda expands the current editor.

I find that a little annoying sometimes, my mouse double clicks more often than I'd like it to...I know I should probably get a new mouse but come on...Is there a way to disable this feature?

I've already tried all kinds of settings and still couldn't find a way